# How to get GPS location from android app widget?

Tags: android, gps, location, android-appwidget

I am new in android programming, and I have a task to make a standalone android widget (app widget), which sends some data to PHP server. I need to find a way to get current device location from the widget class. The widget class is called Alarm and it extends AppWidgetProvider, and it should be launched without Activity.

I have found many examples explaining how to get GPS location using LocationManager and LocationListener from MainActivity, but it's not what I need, I need it to be without activity, only widget.

I'll appreciate any idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably will need to create a background service that gets your location and then sends it in a defined period to your PHP server.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a task to make a standalone android widget (app widget), which sends some data to PHP server. I need to find a way to get current device location from the widget class.

An app widget cannot "send send some data" to a server, and an app widget cannot "get current device location". An app widget — in the form of an `AppWidgetProvider` — lives for a millisecond or so, long enough to publish an update to its portion of the home screen's UI. **That's it**. Your entire process may be terminated within milliseconds after you return from `onUpdate()`.

Create a `Service` (e.g., a `JobService` on Android 5.0+) that:

- Registers for location updates
- When it receives the location update, sends the data to the server
- If appropriate (since we do not know what the actual UI of the app widget is), use `AppWidgetManager` to update the app widget's UI
- Stops itself

When and how you schedule the service to do its work is up to you (`JobScheduler` and a `JobService` would be a fine choice).

Comment: Thanks, I will try to go that way.